# generating buttons after a if statement in wxPython

Tags: python, wxpython

I have wxPython application were user gives a file as an input, and then my program should generate 2 dropdown lists for each line from the file. Problem is that no buttons are generated after user gives a file as an input, this is done in menu and self.content gets it's items. I have tried to call myButtons method after user gives the file, but it didn't work either.

Here is my simplified code for buttons:

```
class size:
    def __init__(self, id, name):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name

class type:
    def __init__(self, id, name):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name

class GUI(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        self.dirname = ''
        self.content = ''

        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, size=(700, 400))

        #UI stuff
        panelControl = wx.Panel(self, 1, style=wx.MAXIMIZE) 
        sizerControl = wx.GridBagSizer(hgap=4,vgap = 4)

        self.menu()
        #buttons
        if not self.content == '':
            self.myButtons()


    def myButtons(self): 
        listOfObjects = self.content #list if lists
        #content of the dropdown lists
        sizes = [size(0, 'very small'), size(1, 'small'), size(2, 'medium'), size(3, 'large'), size(4,'very large')]
        types = [type(0, 'UI'), type(1, 'text'), type(2, 'I/O'), type(3, 'calculation'), 
            type(4, 'set-up'), type(5,  'logic'), type(6, 'data')]

        for i in listOfObjects:
            lista = [] #save the dropdown list selections
            panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)
            self.labelthing = wx.StaticText(panel, label="Object name: %s LOC: %s Method amount: %s Mean: %s"%(i[0], i[1], i[2], i[3]))
            self.sizeDrop = wx.ComboBox(panel,
                          size=wx.DefaultSize,
                          choices=lista)

            self.typeDrop = wx.ComboBox(panel,
                          size=wx.DefaultSize,
                          choices=lista)

            self.widgetMaker(self.sizeDrop, self.typeDrop)    
            self.Show()


    def widgetMaker(self, widget1, widget2):
        widget1.Bind(wx.EVT_COMBOBOX, self.onSelect)
        widget2.Bind(wx.EVT_COMBOBOX, self.onSelect)


    def onSelect(self, event):
        #wait for the both dropdown list values, then do stuff
        pass

    def menu(self):
        #do other stuff too
        self.content = [['foo1', 1 , 'bar1', 1],['foo2', 1 , 'bar2', 1]]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    frame = GUI(None, -1, "") 
    frame.Show(1)
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: I don't see why it doesn't work, maybe create a http://wiki.wxpython.org/MakingSampleApps so one can run it.

Comment: Edited it so that it can be runned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several issues. For one, you overwrite the widgets in your loop in each iteration. The panel doesn't get overwritten, but the comboboxes and the static text do. So the bindings to the first two comboboxes may not work the way you expect since they are bound to the 2nd instance of the widgets. You are also using `wx.PySimpleApp` which is deprecated. You should be using `wx.App(False)` instead.

Also note that your code will not run as you never imported `wx`.

I edited your code a bit to make it work, but I did not fix all the issues with it:

```
import wx 

class size:
    def __init__(self, id, name):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name

class type:
    def __init__(self, id, name):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name

class GUI(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        self.dirname = ''
        self.content = ''

        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, size=(700, 400))
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)

        #UI stuff
        #panelControl = wx.Panel(self, 1, style=wx.MAXIMIZE) 
        sizerControl = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        self.menu()
        #buttons
        if not self.content == '':
            self.myButtons(sizerControl)

        self.panel.SetSizer(sizerControl)
        self.panel.Layout()

        self.Show()


    def myButtons(self, sizerControl): 
        listOfObjects = self.content #list if lists
        #content of the dropdown lists
        sizes = [size(0, 'very small'), size(1, 'small'), size(2, 'medium'), size(3, 'large'), size(4,'very large')]
        types = [type(0, 'UI'), type(1, 'text'), type(2, 'I/O'), type(3, 'calculation'), 
            type(4, 'set-up'), type(5,  'logic'), type(6, 'data')]

        for i in listOfObjects:
            lista = [] #save the dropdown list selections
            panel = wx.Panel(self.panel, wx.ID_ANY)
            nested_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
            self.labelthing = wx.StaticText(panel, label="Object name: %s LOC: %s Method amount: %s Mean: %s"%(i[0], i[1], i[2], i[3]))
            nested_sizer.Add(self.labelthing, 0, wx.ALL, 5)

            self.sizeDrop = wx.ComboBox(panel,
                          size=wx.DefaultSize,
                          choices=lista)
            nested_sizer.Add(self.sizeDrop, 0, wx.ALL, 5)

            self.typeDrop = wx.ComboBox(panel,
                          size=wx.DefaultSize,
                          choices=lista)
            nested_sizer.Add(self.typeDrop, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
            panel.SetSizer(nested_sizer)


            #self.widgetMaker(self.sizeDrop, self.typeDrop)
            sizerControl.Add(panel, 1, wx.EXPAND, 5)


    def widgetMaker(self, widget1, widget2):
        widget1.Bind(wx.EVT_COMBOBOX, self.onSelect)
        widget2.Bind(wx.EVT_COMBOBOX, self.onSelect)


    def onSelect(self, event):
        #wait for the both dropdown list values, then do stuff
        pass

    def menu(self):
        #do other stuff too
        self.content = [['foo1', 1 , 'bar1', 1],['foo2', 1 , 'bar2', 1]]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = GUI(None, -1, "")
    app.MainLoop()
```

You will note that I swapped out the GridBagSizer for a regular BoxSizer to make this simpler to demonstrate. I used the Widget Inspection Tool to help me figure out what was going on. You should check it out:

- http://wiki.wxpython.org/Widget%20Inspection%20Tool